# How can I push a local android studio project to gitlab in an existing folder in the master branch?

Tags: java, android, git, gitlab, repository

I have 3 local projects on my computer
project1,
project2
and project3

In gitlab I have an existing repository. There is the master branch in this are 3 existing folders:
project1,
project2
and project3

How can I push the contents/project of my local project folders into the respective matching project folder in the master branch?

So that the contents from the local folder project 1 are also in the same folder project 1 in the repository. And so on.

I tried with project 1, but the files from this folder are now all in a new main branch. These should be in the master branch in the correct folder.

Can someone help me here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am assuming that you have already added all files to the staging area. now you should check your branch by running this command on terminal :

```
git branch
```

it will show your current branch either **main** or **master**

if your current branch is main branch then run these commands it will push your code to master branch

```
1. Git checkout master 
2. Git pull origin main
3. Git push origin master
```

if you need more help please let me know in comments.

Comment: Will these pushing my project directly to the correct folder in the master branch? For example, if I have my project 1 open I am in the main branch and execute these commands, how can I push them directly to the correct folder in the master branch?

Comment: for ex : if you make changes inside project 1 then only project 1 folder will be updated on remote

Comment: How can I connect my git repo with my local files? with the git checkout master in the terminal i get the message "error: pathspec 'master' did not match any files known to git

Comment: first of all check your remote url with this command :
git remote -v

if this shows the correct url then pull the changes from remote repo to local and then set upstream branch

Comment: I got the message fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): git.
So first I have to use the command git clone [url], right? To clone the existing remote repo to my local computer?
After that I have to go to the correct branch with git branch master. 
But how to proceed?
If I use git pull afterwards won't my local data be overwritten with the remote data? There is no data in the remote repository except for the project folders. But in my local project folder the project is already finished.

Comment: yes first clone the existing project then pull the changes and your data won’t be overwritten but for the save side i recommend  that you should make backup of your project.

Comment: Okay thanks, now I have the right remote url check it with git remote -v. After that I use git checkout master to go to the master branch. Now im on the master branch. Can I simply use git push now to push my project to the right remote folder? Or what is the correct push command?

Comment: git push origin master use this for push

Comment: I have now done that, but nothing has changed in the remote repo unfortunately. I do not know what is wrong.

Comment: did you check your remote repo branch is it main or master? or are you sure code pushed successfully to remote branch? did you commit the code?